# How can I rewrite laptop.example.com to www.example.com/?c=1 using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite:

- `laptop.example.com` to `www.example.com/?c=1`.
- `phone.example.com` to `www.example.com/?c=2`

It doesn't have to be dynamic or anything. I just want a handful of hardcoded rewrites.

**Currently I am trying this, and it is redirecting, not rewriting:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^laptop.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/?c=1$1 [QSA,L]
```

mod rewrite syntax is so baffling to me, I cannot make head or tail out of it.

I do not want to do a 301 redirect. I want to do URL rewrite so that user sees the original subdomain URL without the parameters, but internally it is sent as the latter ones.

I already have several rewrites in my .htaccess file; they should be applied *after* this rewrite.

*I have looked at about a dozen similar questions in SO. But I couldn't convert the answers to my specific needs; I couldn't find out what I was missing or what I was doing wrong. That is why I am asking it again specifically for my scenario.*

---

**Working Code:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^laptop.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ ?c=1$1 [QSA,L]
```

Hopefully I won't encounter a situation where other rewrites below this mess it up again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are redirecting because anything you have an `http://` or `https://` in your rewrite rule's target, it implicitly 302 redirects. If the 2 hosts you have sit on different webservers or document roots, you'd need to use a reverse proxy in order for the address bar of your browser not to change. But it looks like (after looking at your actual website) that both hosts are on the same server and share the same root. So you simply need to do get rid of the `http://www.findbyall.com` from your target:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^laptop.findbyall.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?c=1$1 [QSA,L]
```

You probably also want to change the `^(.*)$`regex to `^/?$` if you don't want it to match everything.

Comment: Removing the domain solved the redirect problem. Also, the original `^(.*)$` not only didn't work, it produced a 500 server error when left as such. So I changed it to `^/?$` like you suggested. The whole thing is working now, I've updated the question with the working code. Thanks!